# Nested css grid is not displaying nested items

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm having an issue with a nested CSS GRID - the nested grid items are not displaying correctly - have checked the markup over and over, but I d not see the error.

the first grid row should span three columns (which it does) and the grid item is set as a display:grid with 2 child grid items,  the child items are not spanning the correct columns.

Can anyone explain why this is not working?

FIDDLE HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/qL683ubz/1/

here is the css:

```
.insights-grid-container {
    display: grid;
    max-width: 998px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: 300px 300px 300px 300px 300px;
    grid-gap: 5px 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.insights-grid-container div {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.insights-grid-container > div > div:first-child {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* row, column, row, column */
.insights-grid-container .article.hero  {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 3;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: 300px;
    grid-gap: 5px 5px;
    background-color: #cc0000;
}
    .insights-grid-container > .article.hero > div:first-child {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 2;
    }
    .insights-grid-container > .article.hero > div:last-child {
        grid-area: 1 / 3 / span 1 / span 1;
    }





.insights-grid-container > .article.event {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: 90px;
}

.insights-grid-container > .article.aside-left {}
.insights-grid-container > .article.aside-right {}
```

and here is the grid:

```
<div class="insights-grid-container">

    <div class="article hero">
        <div style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/600x300);" />image</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="article aside-left">
        <div style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x300);" />1 </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="article"><h3>2</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
    <div class="article"><h3>3</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
    <div class="article"><h3>4</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
    <div class="article"><h3>5</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>


    <div class="article aside-right">
        <div style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x300);" />1 </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="article"><h3>2</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
    <div class="article"><h3>3</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
    <div class="article"><h3>4</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
    <div class="article"><h3>5</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>

    <div class="article event"><h3>event</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: opening/closing div aren't good for the image

Comment: You may try use real `<img>` tags instead of background images. Background images do not stretch the div. The div is as wide as it's content (auto)

Comment: @enxaneta That's irrelevant in grids.

Comment: Félix Gagnon-Grenier thank you for your comment: he has `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;`

Comment: @enxaneta I addressed the difference in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subgrids are actually unaware (with the current level 1 grid specification) of any and all grids that happen anywhere up (or down) in the dom.

When an element has the `display: grid` property, a *new* grid is defined. Grid rules will apply only to the very first level children of that grid element.

That being said, I believe what you wish for instead of the `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;` rules is `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;`. That will prevent a non-existing image to be shrinked to its non existing content.

`fr` is the ["fraction"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#The_fr_Unit) measurement unit. `1fr 1fr 1fr` instructs the grid to have three tracks (it works in both direction, row and column) which share exactly the space that is left after giving other hard rules of placing.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qL683ubz/4/) is an updated fiddle where the first element of the subgrid correctly (if I understand correctly) spans the two first columns.

Comment: hmmm.. I read the docs/spec as the 'auto' was suposed to automatically adjust widths equally.  I guess not, though take a peek at my fiddle again - I had updated it to account for the aside-left and aside-right 2 row high items that are working without the FR syntax!

Comment: @Sean Heh, interesting. It seems however that the article hero nowspans *three* columns? (I manually entered 6 in the revisions number of the jsfille to get there, is it the correct one?)

Comment: actually - I think I found the source, there were some unused classes in the css (I inherited the project)  referring to .hero having a max width larger than the grid container .... very strange.